# Cannot establish remote mysql! Access denied for root@localhost

Tags: mysql

I recently decided to move just some websites from one hosting to another, but I wanted to keep all the databases on old hosting.

What i did was transfer all the domains & files I needed, and in every website's dbconfig, changed ''localhost'' to old server's ip. Also I whitelisted new server's IP to access MySQL.

When i try accessing any website that estabilshes DB connection, I get error

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

The funny thing is that I don't have ''localhost'' set up & also my users aren't ''root''. Where is it getting this false info from?

Example of my DBConnection

```
    <?php
//database Host
    $dbhost = "198.57.246.***";
//username for db
    $dbuser = "toms**_rustu";
//password for db
    $dbpass = "Nb******";
//database Name
    $dbname = "toms**_rust";

//loginSeed
//Connect to MySQL Server
    $dbcon = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
//Select Database
    mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

//create users table

?>
```

Comment: my dbconfig looks like this (edited)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Can this b the problem? I don't care about my code ethics, I need DB connection!

Comment: There must be something else happening here which we can't see. The error message suggests you are using the user root and connecting to the local mysql. Your example code should be connecting to somewhere else. Are you sure your config is not being overridden somewhere? Perhaps there's another bit of code which tries to connect?